# D3 Legend Placement

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have a donut chart with lots of labels and need place the labels preferably in a an unorder list so they will resize based on the size of the parent element. 
I am going off of this example: http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-3-adding-a-legend

I still don't fully understand D3 and working quick to use it. Thanks for any suggestions you have!!

Here is my code.
**JS**

```
(function(d3) {
   'use strict';

   var width = 760;
   var height = 760;
   var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
   var donutWidth = 275;
   var legendRectSize = 18;
   var legendSpacing = 4;

   var color = d3.scale.category20b();

   var svg = d3.select('#chart')
     .append('svg')
     .attr('width', width)
     .attr('height', height)
     .append('g')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
       ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

   var arc = d3.svg.arc()
     .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
     .outerRadius(radius);

   var pie = d3.layout.pie()
     .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
     .sort(null);

   var tooltip = d3.select('#chart')
     .append('div')
     .attr('class', 'tooltip');

   tooltip.append('div')
     .attr('class', 'label');

   tooltip.append('div')
     .attr('class', 'count');

   tooltip.append('div')
     .attr('class', 'percent');

   d3.json('http://localhost:8080/product_sales/123/2014.01.01/2014.12.31', function(error, data) {

     console.log(dataset);
     var dataset = [];
      for (var key in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var obj = {
          count: data[key],
          enabled:true,
          label:key
        };
        dataset.push(obj);
        }
      }

     var path = svg.selectAll('path')
       .data(pie(dataset))
       .enter()
       .append('path')
       .attr('d', arc)
       .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
         return color(d.data.label);
       })
       .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

     path.on('mouseover', function(d) {
       var total = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) {
         return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0;
       }));
       var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10;
       tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.label);
       tooltip.select('.count').html("$"+d.data.count);
       tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%');
       tooltip.style('display', 'block');
     });

     path.on('mouseout', function() {
       tooltip.style('display', 'none');
     });


     path.on('mousemove', function(d) {
       console.log((d3.event.pageX - 100)+', '+(d3.event.pageY + 10));
       tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.offsetY+10) + 'px')
         .style('left', (d3.event.offsetX+10) + 'px');
     });



     var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
       .data(color.domain())
       .enter()
       .append('g')
       .attr('class', 'legend')
       .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
         var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
         var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
         var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
         var vert = i * height - offset;
         return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
       });

     legend.append('rect')
       .attr('width', legendRectSize)
       .attr('height', legendRectSize)
       .style('fill', color)
       .style('stroke', color)
       .on('click', function(label) {
         var rect = d3.select(this);
         var enabled = true;
         var totalEnabled = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) {
           return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0;
         }));

         if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') {
           rect.attr('class', '');
         } else {
           if (totalEnabled < 2) return;
           rect.attr('class', 'disabled');
           enabled = false;
         }

         pie.value(function(d) {
           if (d.label === label) d.enabled = enabled;
           return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0;
         });

         path = path.data(pie(dataset));

         path.transition()
           .duration(750)
           .attrTween('d', function(d) {
             var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
             this._current = interpolate(0);
             return function(t) {
               return arc(interpolate(t));
             };
           });
       });

     legend.append('text')
       .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
       .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
       .text(function(d) { return d; });

   });

 })(window.d3);
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pie</title>
<style>
 h1{
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
#chart {
  height: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 760px;
}
.tooltip {
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 95px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.legend {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  float:left;
}
rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
rect.disabled {
  fill: transparent !important;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>


 <script src="../bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/tip/new.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The example you link to will place the legend according to the size and position of the parent element.  Are you just trying to size it down as the number of slices becomes large?  What is your plan for when the font-size becomes too small to read?

Comment: I'd prefer to place each element inline with the other underneath to chart.